# A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected

Tags: wcf, sockets, tcp

I am trying to connect to a remote external server using TCP sockets in WCF code 
My WCF service is the client which has code using sockets to connect to an external server.
This code sends a request to an external server and receives the server response

```
int byteCount = 0;
        Socket m_socClient;
        try
        {

            string query = "My Request String";
            m_socClient = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            System.Net.IPAddress remoteIPAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("127:0:0:0");
            System.Net.IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = new System.Net.IPEndPoint(remoteIPAddress, 1234);
            EVCommon.Log("COnnecting to" + IPSelected + Port);
            m_socClient.Connect(remoteEndPoint);
            try
            {
            if (m_socClient.Connected)
            {
                EVCommon.Log("Connected to" + IPSelected + Port);   
                var reQuestToSend = string.Format("POST /ZZZZZ HTTP/1.1\r\nContent-Length:{0}\r\n\r\n{1}", query.Length, query);
                byte[] bytesToSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(reQuestToSend);
                byteCount = m_socClient.Send(bytesToSend, SocketFlags.None);
                byte[] bytesReceived = new byte[1024];
                byteCount = m_socClient.Receive(bytesReceived, SocketFlags.None);
                Response271 = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceived);
                m_socClient.Disconnect(false);
                m_socClient.Close(5000);
            }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                EVCommon.Log(ex.Message);

            }


        }
```

If I make a windows application with the same client code to connect to the remote server, it is successful. I am able to connect, send and receive
This error occurs only when I bring WCF into the picture. The code fails at if(m_socket.Connected). So it is not able to connect successfully.

```
A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket 
is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied.
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that the windows applications runs in the identity of the logged in user and the WCF service runs in the identity of the application pool.

What is probably happening is that the application pool is running as NETWORK SERVICE which does not have the right to open a port.

Try changing the identity of the app pool to your user to check if this is the problem.